# How to get UITextView text while user is still editing it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I use 
 `[self.assuntoTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(testarSeTemTexto)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];`

to get the text value of the `UITextFields`, but I can't do the same with `UITextViews`, how can I do that WHILE user is still editing the TextView?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need validation and simply want to be informed that the text had been changed simply assign a delegate to this `UITextField` (if yiu haven't done this yet) and implement a method

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSString *text = textView.text;
}
```

If you want to implement some kind of validation then the proper method to use would be

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *finalTextWillBe = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                                        withString:string];

    //validation comes here... 

    if (final text passes your validation) 
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

NOTE: if you are using more than one text field you will have to identify the source somehow. Either by setting its `tag` or by holding a reference (ivar, property...) to the text fields.

Answer (score 1):

Make your viewController a delegate of textView like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
```

This is your delegate method:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html) for more info

Comment: FYI - it's better to add the protocol to the class extension in the .m file. There is no need to publicly announce to the world that the class deals with text views.

Comment: @achievelimitless The use of the text view delegate and the notification are separate and independent. And what does the statement "*Now write your logic in this notification*" actually mean?

Comment: @rmaddy.. with respect _/\\_ In the statement, I am asking the person to write the purposeful code, for which he needed this answer. Let me know if I am wrong somewhere ..:)

Comment: I think the point @maddy is making is that notifications have nothing to do with conforming to `UITextViewDelegate`.